# enable or disable QDialogButtonBox based on the text of multiple QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to enable or disable the QDialogButtonBox or preferably only the OK button in QDialog, based on the selected text of two QComboBox(es).

My Example is as below. It is currently not working and the two ComboBoxes work independently of each other when enabling or disabling the QDialogButtonBox.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSignalMapper, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QGroupBox, QFormLayout, QLabel, QComboBox,
                             QApplication, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox,
                             QVBoxLayout)


class SheetColumns(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, column_header):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Input Column Names")

        self.column_headers = column_header

        self.column_headers.insert(0, ' ')
        self.setWhatsThis('Please match columns in your data sheet names'
                          ' with the right side labels')

        col_names = ["Student Name:", "Student ID:", "Cohort:", "Gender:",
                     "College:", "Department:", "Major:", "Minor", "Email:",
                     "Adviser", "Adviser Email"]
        self.form_group_box = QGroupBox("Specify Column Names")
        self.layout = QFormLayout()
        for col_name in col_names:
            combo = QComboBox()
            combo.addItems(self.column_headers)
            self.layout.addRow(QLabel(col_name), combo)
        self.form_group_box.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button_box = QDialogButtonBox(
            QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)

        self.button_box.setEnabled(False)

        self.layout.itemAt(0, 1).widget().currentTextChanged.connect(
            self.check_validity)
        self.layout.itemAt(1, 1).widget().currentTextChanged.connect(
            self.check_validity)

        self.button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.form_group_box)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def check_validity(self, text):
        print(text)
        if text == ' ':
            self.button_box.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.button_box.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = SheetColumns(['name student', 'id', 'cohort', 'test 1'])
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

I would like the QDialogButtonBox to be enabled when the currentText(s) in both ComboBoxes are something other than ' ', while it is being disabled when they are both ' '.

I attempted to use `QSignalMapper`.

However, I could not manage to make it work.

```
class SheetColumns(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, column_header):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Input Column Names")

        self.column_headers = column_header

        self.column_headers.insert(0, ' ')
        self.setWhatsThis('Please match columns in your data sheet names'
                          ' with the right side labels')

        col_names = ["Student Name:", "Student ID:", "Cohort:", "Gender:",
                     "College:", "Department:", "Major:", "Minor", "Email:",
                     "Adviser", "Adviser Email"]
        self.form_group_box = QGroupBox("Specify Column Names")
        self.layout = QFormLayout()
        for col_name in col_names:
            combo = QComboBox()
            combo.addItems(self.column_headers)
            self.layout.addRow(QLabel(col_name), combo)
        self.form_group_box.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button_box = QDialogButtonBox(
            QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)

        self.button_box.setEnabled(False)

        self.mapper = QSignalMapper(self)

        comb_bx1 = self.layout.itemAt(0, 1).widget()
        comb_bx2 = self.layout.itemAt(1, 1).widget()

        comb_bx1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.mapper.map)
        comb_bx2.currentTextChanged.connect(self.mapper.map)

        self.mapper.setMapping(comb_bx1, comb_bx1.currentText())
        self.mapper.setMapping(comb_bx2, comb_bx2.currentText())

        self.mapper.mapped.connect(self.check_validity)

        self.button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.form_group_box)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def check_validity(self, text):
        print(text)
        if text == ' ':
            self.button_box.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.button_box.setEnabled(True)
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, or is there any better approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using QSignalMapper is oversized for what you require, in your case you just have to iterate over the QComboBox and verify that they do not have the appropriate option and according to that enable the button as shown below:

```py
class SheetColumns(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, column_header, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Input Column Names")

        self.column_headers = column_header

        self.setWhatsThis(
            "Please match columns in your data sheet names"
            " with the right side labels"
        )

        col_names = [
            "Student Name:",
            "Student ID:",
            "Cohort:",
            "Gender:",
            "College:",
            "Department:",
            "Major:",
            "Minor",
            "Email:",
            "Adviser",
            "Adviser Email",
        ]

        self.combos = []

        flay = QFormLayout()
        for i, col_name in enumerate(col_names):
            combo = QComboBox()
            combo.addItems([""] + self.column_headers)
            flay.addRow(col_name, combo)
            if i in (0, 1):
                combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.check_validity)
                self.combos.append(combo)

        self.form_group_box = QGroupBox("Specify Column Names")
        self.form_group_box.setLayout(flay)

        self.button_box = QDialogButtonBox(
            QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        )
        self.button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.form_group_box)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_box)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def check_validity(self):
        is_enabled = True
        for combo in self.combos:
            if not combo.currentText():
                is_enabled = False
                break
        button = self.button_box.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        button.setEnabled(is_enabled)
```

---

<sub>[@TheKewlStore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3715974/thekewlstore) has pointed out something incorrect in his answer: The ownership of the QObjects is not handled by Python but by the C++ part. The ownership of a QObject in python has the class where it was created if it is an attribute, which in the example of the OP is not met, or that has another QObject that is its parent that is set when creating it or using the setParent() method. In the case of QWidget when you add it to a layout, it sets the widget it manages as parent. In your case, the ownership of the QComboBoxes is the QGroupBox, so there are no problems with the GC.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find signal mapper extremely confusing and avoid it like the plague. Here is how I would do this (going to use a dummy class to make life easier):

```
class DummyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.combo_box_1 = QComboBox()
        self.combo_box_2 = QComboBox()
        self.combo_1_text = ""  # This could also be self.combo_box_1.text()
        self.combo_2_text = ""
        self.combo_box_1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.combo_one_changed)
        self.combo_box_2.currentTextChanged.connect(self.combo_two_changed)

    def combo_one_changed(self, text):
        self.combo_1_text = text

    def combo_two_changed(self, text):
        self.combo_2_text = text

    def check_validity(self):
        if self.combo_1_text and self.combo_2_text:
            self.button_box.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.button_box.setEnabled(False)
```

Let me know if you have any trouble with this, I just came up with this quickly.

EDIT: I also notice that you are defining your combo boxes as locals in your init method, which may also be a problem because of pyqt's ownership. If you don't store a reference to the object, you're not guaranteed it will stay in existence and python might garbage collect it, meaning you may lose your signal connections altogether. Can't say that this is what's happening, but in general it's safer to keep an instance to them in your init method by setting them as instance variables instead.

Comment: Your "EDIT" is incorrect because when you add a widget to a layout the ownership of the widget will be taken by the widget where the widget was set, in your case the ownership of the QComboBox will be taken by the QGroupBox so there are no problems with the GC.

Comment: Ah that's true I wasn't paying attention to the fact they were part of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) for his answer which perfectly works fine.

The code below better suits my use case and it is quite similar to the answer given by  [@eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) following his concept.

```
class SheetColumns(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, column_header, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Input Column Names")

        self.column_headers = column_header

        self.setWhatsThis(
            "Please match columns in your datasheet names"
            " with the right side labels"
        )

        col_names = [
            "Student Name:",
            "Student ID:",
            "Cohort:",
            "Gender:",
            "College:",
            "Department:",
            "Major:",
            "Minor",
            "Email:",
            "Adviser",
            "Adviser Email",
        ]

        self.combos = []

        flay = QFormLayout()
        for i, col_name in enumerate(col_names):
            combo = QComboBox()
            combo.addItems([""] + self.column_headers)
            flay.addRow(col_name, combo)
            if i in (0, 1):
                combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.check_validity)
                self.combos.append(combo)

        self.form_group_box = QGroupBox("Specify Column Names")
        self.form_group_box.setLayout(flay)

        self.button_box = QDialogButtonBox(
            QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        )
        self.button = self.button_box.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        self.button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setText('Student Name and ID cannot be empty')

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.form_group_box)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_box)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def check_validity(self):
        if all([combo.currentText() for combo in self.combos]):
            self.button.setEnabled(True)
            self.label.setText('')
        else:
            self.button.setEnabled(False)
            self.label.setText('Student Name and ID cannot be empty')
```

Comment: change `self.label.setText('')` to  `self.label.clear()`, is more readable.